# How are these evaluated as true?

Tags: c++

Consider the following examples:

```
int x;
if (x = 1)
    //...


if (std::cout << "Is it true?")
    //...
```

Both are evaluated as true, but why?

Comment: @PiotrNycz int, edited the question.

Comment: Please don't modify your question to a complete different one like that, it would confuse people as some of the answers don't make sense now.

Comment: Please don't add _additional_ (and unrelated) questions in your edits. Your "7" question is undefined behaviour, BTW. The compiler is allowed to make daemons fly out of your nose for this.

Comment: You're going through your exam questions with us, don't you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I love C++ and I love thinking about questions like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first one, you're assigning the value of `1` to `x`.  A non-zero value will always evaluate to true in a condition.

For the second one, when `std::cout << "Is it true?"` is called, operator<< will return a reference to `std::cout`.  At that point, the condition is simply reduced to:

```
if (std::cout)
    //
```

This is now evaluating whether or not `std::cout` is in a [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) state.

Answer (score 4):

The `if (x = 1)` is essentially the same as `tmp = (x = 1); if (tmp) ...`

The "result" of `operator << (const char *)` is an `ostream&`, which has an `operator bool` that the compiler calls to make it "comparable". `operator bool` will return "false if there was an error, otherwise true". Before C++11, it would return a `void*`, but the meaning was the same ("false (= 0) if there is an error, true otherwise".

Answer (score 3):

The result of assignment is its left operand, so the value of `x = 1` is its left operand `x`, which has the value of `1` now. And any non-zero integer is treated as true in the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Because `x = 1` is an assignment setting `x` to `1`, not a comparison for equality. Comparison is done via `x == 1`.

It is a common mistake. Often people write `1 == x` to catch these errors, since assignment to a constant triggers a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the assignment result for `x` as mentioned in the other answers the

```
 if (std::cout << "Is it true?")
```

evaluates to `true`, because the statement is equivalent to

```
 if ((std::cout << "Is it true?").good())
```

which checks for the stream state of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements return a value other than `0` and are thus considered to be "true".

If you assign a value to a variable, the result of that statement is the assigned value so you can assign multiple variables at once. For example, `foo = bar = baz = 1`. This works because `baz = 1` yields `1`, which is then assigned to `bar`, then to `foo`. So `x = 1` has the value `1` and is thus true.

Next, the `std::cout << "foo"`: the [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) on a ostream returns the ostream so you can do things like `std::cout << "foo" << "bar";`. Again, there is a value returned that is not `0` and thus true.

Answer (score 0):

In this condition `x = 1` you firstly assign `1` to your `x` variable, and then test x, so it is exactly the same with:

```
x = 1;
if( x ) // which is 1, so true
```

About the output operator `<<`, the compiler will return `true` if the output-stream's state `cout` is ok. So it is not going to be a valid stream if some error occurs.